# C++ Program Bug

Tags: c++, debugging

Given an array. Program should find all pairs the sum of which is can divided by 7. I write this code, but code did not pass all tests

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int m[7];

int main() {
     int n, k = 0;
     cin>>n;
     long long a;
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          cin>>a;
          a %= 7;
          if(m[(7 - a) % 7] > 0) {
               k += m[(7 - a) % 7];
          }
          m[a]++;
     }
     cout<<k;
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply used a hash to store the frequencies of remainders when divided by 7:

```
int count7Divisibiles(int arr[], int n)
{
    // Create a frequency array to count 
    // occurrences of all remainders when 
    // divided by 7
    int freq[7] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    // Count occurrences of all remainders
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ++freq[arr[i] % 7];

    // If both pairs are divisible by '7'
    int ans = freq[0] * (freq[0] - 1) / 2;


    // If one of them is equal
    // to 1 modulo 7 and the
    // other is equal to 3 
    // modulo 7
    ans += freq[1] * freq[6];

    // for 2%7 and 5%7
    ans += freq[2] * freq[5];

    //for 3%7 and 4%7
    ans += freq[3] * freq[4];

    return ans;
}
```

- If both are divisible by 7, then use `n*(n-1)/2`
- Else do `count(a%7)*count((7-a)%7)`

Comment: Hey, Thank you! I don't understand your last two sentences. Can you explain, please?

Comment: for a subset like: `[7, 14, 21, 28]` there are 6 possible pairs. And for a set like `[8, 15, 27, 34]` there are 2*2=4 possible pairs. Please mark it accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: What `count` mean?

Comment: frequency of modulo

Comment: OMG! Why I'm so stupid?? Can you write whole code, please?

Comment: this is the whole code, lol

Comment: hmmm, why this code does not pass all tests??

Comment: Anyway, THANK YOU!

Comment: this should be the logic, don't know why it isnt passing all the cases. can you link me to the problem?

Comment: John has an array A , consisting of N integers. He believes that the number 7 is a lucky number, and he believes that a pair of two numbers is happy if their sum is divided by 7 without a remainder. He wants to know how many such happy pairs ( A i + A j ) mod 7 = 0 in array A , where (1 ≤  i  <  j  ≤  N ) and the operation a mod b means taking the remainder from dividing a by b . Write a program to find the number of happy couples in the array A .

Comment: Input data:
The first line contains one integer N (1 ≤  N  ≤ 10e5 ) .

The second line contains N integers representing the elements of the array (1 ≤  A i  ≤ 10e9 ) .

Output:
Output one number representing the number of happy couples.

Comment: i meant the link to the coding problem, where i can check the my code by running it

Comment: website link!!!

Comment: You have not premission

Comment: okk... give me a min

Comment: i submitted it and it was correct, changed `int` to `long long`

Comment: OMG!!! THANK YOU!!!! Very stupid mistake

Comment: I have not enough reputation((( sorry((

Comment: no problem :) it's okay

Comment: but i have another account)

Comment: sure ... thatwould be helpful